# Can not make logical sense of this mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having a real problem writing the query I need to solve this. The problem is:

For each question that was on more than one quiz, list the following:
the question id,
the quiz date of the first quiz,
the number of students who chose answer A on the first quiz,
the quiz date of the second quiz,
and the number of students who chose answer A on the second quiz
The question id should be the major sort key. The first quiz date listed should be the  minor sort key.

The column name for the first quiz should be FirstQuiz. The column name for the number of students who chose answer A on the first quiz should be FirstA. The column name for the second quiz should be SecondQuiz. The column name for the number of students who chose answer A on the second quiz should be SecondA.
Do not use the
INNER JOIN
format for joining tables.

```
SELECT QuestionId, min(QuizDate), NumChoseA
FROM quizquestions
GROUP BY QuizNum;
```

As you can see, I am nowhere near what I need to have to solve the problem

[I have put in a link to a pastebin containing the database, so that you can see what I am working with.](http://pastebin.com/iPvu5yBW)

Comment: It sounds like you want a [PIVOT](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/) query.

Comment: give me a few minutes, I'll go read that and see what sense I can make of it

Comment: Be careful with MySQL...if you don't get your group by syntax right, MySQL is going to do the wrong thing and not return an error.  You'll need to create a subquery to do the counts of answerA by quiz question and join that back to your main query. Unsure if this is a pivot query though, maybe paqogomez sees something I'm missing.

Comment: You should also try pairing down your pastebin to something a little more consumable.  Wading through all that can make even the nicest volunteer rather grumpy.

Comment: @Twelfth, check the pastebin link at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Ok. So, per my instructions, I have to use material thats already been covered, and PIVOT tables are not included.

Comment: this is homework? meh...you should be learning how to do this yourself. Have you covered self joins?  I can make it work if you've covered CTE's, subqueries, and self joins

Comment: Briefly, and in no detail. While I tend do agree with you that I should learn it myself, its an online course, with very little interaction with the class and professor, so I reach out to places like here for some added social help.

Comment: The following query gets me halfway, but after this I am lost: "SELECT QuizNum, QuestionId, MIN(QuizDate) AS FirstA, NumChoseA
FROM quizquestions
GROUP BY QuizNum;".. I cant figure out how to get the next down date.

Comment: understood...lets create a working answer and go from there...see the answer below, I'll finish it off tomorrow with you.  Please don't accept my word for it, take your time and discover the techniques being used outside of just this answer here :)

Answer (score 0):

I can kick you in the right direction at very least.

```
select questionid, min(quizdate) as 'firstquiz'
from  QuizQuestions
group by questionid
having count(1) > 1
```

The query above will grab all questionID's and their firstquiz date (via the minimum).  The having clause is a filter based on an aggregate, in this case we are getting all that have more than 2 records (I think thats your first requirement.

Second requirement...to get the NumChoseA, we need to join the above query to quizquestions (this is the self join I referred to earlier).

```
select a.questionID, a.firstquiz, b.numchosea
from (qry above) a
inner join quizquestions b on a.questionid = b.questionID and a.firstquiz = b.quizdate
```

See how that works?  If you have a minimum/maximum aggregate statement, you need to ensure the group by only has the fields that you want it to be grouped by (in this case questionID).  If we included numchoseA on in the first query at the top, we would have grouped by numchoseA and gotten back a questionID/quizdate for each unique value of numchooseA, which we didn't want.  --hopefully that blurb made sense...

Second bit is to grab the 'second' occourence.  THis is a bit harder as we need to build a subquery to find questionID,min(quizdate) where the first date for that question isn't included. My preference was a CTE.

Hopefully thats a start...I'm leaving for the day...comment questions and we'll step through the next part tomorrow if you are here.

Comment: This is where I am now, and its not going right at all. "select a.questionID, a.firstquiz, b.numchosea
from
    (select questionid,
     min(quizdate) as 'firstquiz'
     from  QuizQuestions
     group by questionid
     having count(1) > 1 )
     as a,
     (select questionid,
        (select max(quizdate)
         from emp
         where quizdate<(select max(quizdate) from a),
      numchosea from QuizQuestions)
WHERE a.questionid = b.questionID and a.firstquiz = b.quizdate;